# JQueryMobile button inline not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following :

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Button</a>
```

The button is shown across the width of the page where the data-inline="true" should show a button as wide as the text in it.

I am using Chrome and the page from www.jquerymobile.com is shown correctly.

Any ideas why this is not working?

JD

Comment: I copied a page from www.jquerymobile.com and saved it to my desktop. That worked and I saw the buttons being displayed correctly. I then copied the html code to my page that on the server side is produced via ASP.NET MVC2 and the problem appears. Is this an mvc 2 issue?

Answer (score 1):

If the page is being served from within an MVC framework there's always the possibility that it's being modified by another part of the framework that is implicitly used.

- First, verify that the raw HTML served from your ASP.NET server includes all the correct data-* attributes.
- Second, inspect the DOM after jQuery Mobile has added the applicable styles.  Compare these with the inspected styles of the offline version.
- Third, double check the CSS you're including doesn't conflict with the correctly styled page.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your links in a div that also specifies data-inline="true"

Andrew

p.s.  The jQueryMobile website does not specify that you need data-inline="true" on their website however you will need to wrap the elements in a div as well as specify data-inline="true" on each element also.

Andrew (ElGueroPesado)